# macOS Ventura/Sonoma auto screen off when locked

Tags: macos, lockscreen

[Change Lock Screen settings on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mh11784/mac)

This seems comprehensive but it does not give me the right information. Right now, when I lock my screen, I want to appreciate the video wallpaper on Sonoma. However, when locked, the screen turns off almost immediately, how do I change that so the screen stays powered on?

Comment: How did you make it that it turns of immediatelly when you lock? mine stays on and it's sooo annoying... and the settings seems to allow configuration to turn off only after 1 minute at the minimum :/

Comment: The behaviour seems pretty random to me. Apple support didn't know what's up either. However, I was able to keep the lock screen on by using caffinenate in terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You need to activate the Screen Saver, not the lock screen.

You can use adjust the screen saver timings, or use Hot Corners (in Desktop & Dock settings) to set a Screen Saver trigger.

Comment: What if I don't want to see the screensaver, just the lock screen?

Comment: You can set your screensaver to be the same as your lock screen in Wallpaper settings. But yes, if you want to have a different screen saver then this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't use the screen saver on my Apple silicon Macbook with Sonoma.

I discovered that if I press the Touch ID button, the Mac will lock and the video wallpaper on Sonoma will display only for 4 seconds before turning the display off. However if I click on Apple logo > Lock Screen (or Ctrl + Cmd + Q) the same will happen but the video wallpaper will show for about 30 seconds instead of 4 seconds. Quite random!

Comment: My answer tells how to increase the screen auto turn off time from 4 seconds to 30 seconds, which may be enough for some people, directly addressing the question asked, which complains about "almost immediate auto turn off". You can find more information on how to edit answers yourself [in the help center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: Well as you can see you didn't actually help me improve my answer and your comment definitely didn't help me feel better at this community, quite the opposite instead, it makes contributing feel like a tedious job because: a) you may get someone first request you to edit your answer, which I don't know how to improve, and also refuses to improve it himself. b) you are later told that it should be a comment instead, so yeah why should I try go write solutions with such a welcome. That's at least what I would feel if I was actually a new contributor to the StackExchange network.

Comment: And no hard feelings of course, I'm just trying to help you be part of a more [welcoming community](https://apple.stackexchange.com/conduct).